# Prevent Auto-download/ install of Apps/Ads on Micromax Phones

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, ads, micromax

android installing apps without my knowledge. It also showing annoying popups.
How to resolve this issue?

Android version : 5.1 Lollipop
Device: Micromax Canvas 6

Everytime i factory reset, it will fix the issue. After some days, it will start to show popups from Amazon, Myntra like shopping sites.
Phone is installing apps in the background.

Comment: Give the screenshot, pls

Comment: This is almost certainly caused by an app you install yourself.

Comment: @DanHulme No its not, because only stock apps can get this access when your device isn't rooted!

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob It's not unknown for malware apps to download other APK files and trick the user into installing them. We've had questions like that before.

Comment: @DanHulme Ok!?! Now I learned something new! I always thought that on a non-rooted device something like that is impossible

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob Anything is possible if you can con the user into clicking "Accept" when you need them to.

Answer (score 1):

As I know every Android OS phone have the option "Auto-update apps" in the Google Play Settings. For the first, I would completly disable that!

On the site of a Micromax Canvas blog, there is already an [article](http://micromaxcanvas.co.in/solve-auto-download-apps-ads-mmx-phones/) about this issue. I found serval solutions below there  ⬇ ⬇ ⬇

---

**If your Device is rooted then our friends of [XDA-Developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/micromax-remotely-installing-unwanted-apps-on-devices/) already have it:**

> 3. Disable the Software Update application
>
> Now that you have gained root access and ADB is up and running, you
>   can continue with disabling the dreaded application responsible for
>   the silent installs and unwanted ads. All you need to do now is to
>   fire up a command prompt, make sure the prompt is at the directory of
>   your ADB binary, and execute the following command:
>
> `adb shell pm disable com.adups.fota`

---

**For non-rooted device you can try to disable the Software Update package:**

1. Go to Settings
2. Apps
3. All Apps
4. Then disable or uninstall there all apps/ packages that are responsible for updates and install. I don't know which and what they're called. I tried to find out but I looks like it is always an other. Whether it's [FWUpgrade.apk](http://techknowzone.com/how-to-stop-auto-download-of-apps-and-ads-on-micromax-smartphones/) or [Software Update](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVYXF5rLS0M) or the app [itself](http://micromaxcanvas.co.in/delete-remove-per-installed-apps-micromax-phones/).

Try also to uncheck: `Settings–>About Phone–> System/Software update`

For more just google itself, I found many other possibilities but I can't list all them.